# Question on integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I need a confirmation and answer about the following problem:

If we have $ g(x)=\ln x+{ x }^{ -1/2 }{ 1 }_{ x\le 1 } $

I'm trying to determine $ \int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ \ln x+{ x }^{ -1/2 }{ 1 }_{ x\le 1 } } $

$$ \int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ \ln x+{ x }^{ -1/2 }{ 1 }_{ x\le 1 } } =\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \ln x+{ x }^{ -1/2 }{ 1 }_{ x\le 1 } } +\int _{ 1 }^{ +\infty  }{ \ln x }  $$

For the first part:

$$\begin{align} \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \ln x+{ x }^{ -1/2 }{ 1 }_{ x\le 1 } } & ={ \left[ x\ln x-x+2\sqrt { x }  \right]  }_{ 0 }^{ 1 }\\ & =1 \ln 1-1+2\sqrt { 1 } -X \ln X-0+2\sqrt { 0 } \\ & =1-X \ln X \end{align}$$

which tends to $1$ at $0$.

For the second part:

$$\begin{align} \int _{ 1 }^{ +\infty  }{ \ln x } ={ \left[ x \ln x-x \right]  }_{ 1 }^{ +\infty  } & =X \ln X-X-1 \ln 1-1 \\ & =X \ln X-X-1 \end{align}$$

This thing tends to $+\infty$ as $X$ grows to $+\infty$.

So for me the whole $\int _{ 0 }^{ +\infty  }{ \ln x+{ x }^{ -1/2 }{ 1 }_{ x\le 1 } }=+\infty$

- Am I correct ?
- Does it mean that this integral is not defined ?
  I'm not sure what it means to say that an integral is not defined.

Thanks in advance please.

Comment: $g$ is not bounded, hence the integral must diverge.

Comment: ok, does it diverge only or can we say it not defined ? Are my calculations ok ?

Comment: You are dealing with improper integrals, hence you have to do a limit. In this case you have something of the type $constant + \infty$ so the result is $+ \infty$. It would not be defined only in the case $+ \infty - \infty$.